# How is a Floating Point PRNG designed

Tags: hardware, floating-point, random-number

Forgive the breadth of my question, but from understanding of basic digital circuits, an integer PRNG outputs a random number by using the XOR of certain bits of a LSFR. using an XOR tap into bits to perform the random bit output.    Based on understanding of the concept from a definition as such,  how does floating point PRNG work, or get implemented as far as blocks of digital circuits.   Or at the very least from a mathematical standpoint using bits of representation of the value to work on.    Is this concept covered in a computer arithmetic course, or more broadly in a VLSI course?

Comment: I'm just pulling this out of my ass but why can't you just randomly generate each bit of the floating point number?

Comment: If I understand the comment, a bit has two states,  of equal Probability of Occurrence.  If it is equally weighted towards both states, maybe I should drill down and ask the concept of a 1 Bit PNRG, which I don't know how to create.   If a 1 bit PNRG is defined,  shift it into the LSFR and perform XOR operation on the bits of concern (which I assume is a polynomial function).    Initial state of a register is 0 so if a 1 is generated by the XOR then it mutates the LSFR output value to some predefined function.    If the PNRG has more XORs, then the generator function changes correspondingly.

Comment: My question is more towards how to generate a floating point number using the LSFR and PNRG function.   Does the PNRG just write individual bits to the corresponding mantissa of a floating point representation.

Comment: I don't know why you couldn't just use the bit directly but I don't know anything about RNGs.

Comment: What do you mean use the bit directly, can you clarify?

Comment: Generate the first bit in the FP register, then the second bit, then the third bit, etc. Until mantissa and exponent are all filled up. Without XOR or anything like that.

Comment: Looks like I assumed a LSFR generates a bit vector at once, but it is a 1 Bit function independent of any consecutive bits in the register.   The PNRG takes 1 bit in, 1 bit out, and operates independently of other bits in this case

Comment: @Vahe Are you unable to access google? Top entry for me was [*A PRNG Specialized in Double Precision Floating Point Numbers Using an Affine Transition*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-04107-5_38). In section 3, they cover the use of an LFSR, right away. It includes excellent references to prior work, as well.

Comment: My apologies for the extended discussion and hesitancy to google,  I will dive deeper,  thank you for the resource provided

Comment: @Vahe Best wishes. I do think it is your responsibility to at least *survey* the existing literature. If for no other reason, than to tell us what you've already found. Better, would be that you skimmed the material enough to find out what is missing from what you feel you need. That would go a long way in clarifying a question like yours. And I think you'd be in a much better position, besides. Again, best wishes on this. Next you write here, perhaps you will teach us a little while asking for our imaginations to help out. That would be good for all, I suspect.

Comment: I will be happy to delete this question for fairness

Comment: @Vahe If the question isn't otherwise removed for reasons beyond your control, please feel free to update it with some good information. I'd like to see what you find out.

Comment: Let me find some references and see if I can understand the polynomial generation functions used in each bit for certain cases,  I can use that to post a simple representation of a digital block to compute the mantissa

Comment: @Vahe Just a side note that there are many ways to implement a PRNG. An LFSR is just one of them. LCG is another one. And what kind of floating point values you mean, as e.g. for audio you generally need range of +/- 1 which also means you can simply generate the mantissa bits and scale the exponent to your liking.

Comment: @Vahe are you truly seeking a *floating point* PRNG, or just a *non-integer* PRNG? Because if you need a non-integer PRNG with a limited range, then by far the easiest approach is to use [fixed-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic), and that's typically the best approach. But if you're truly seeking a random number that can have a magnitude as small as \$10^{−38}\$ and as large as \$10^{38}\$ then yeah, floating point would be the way to go ;-)

Comment: Oh, and in case it wasn't obvious from my previous comment, if you choose fixed-point then the way to generate your non-integer PRNG is simply: step 1) choose any one of the fine integer PRNGs already in existence and then step 2) move the decimal point.

Comment: @Vahe what's the distribution your numbers should have? You need to **very** carefully define that! It's all a bit complicated with floating point numbers, because they are non-uniformly spaced.

Comment: @DKNguyen you can not just put random bits into a float and hope for any sensible distribution of numbers – due to the floating point nature, there are multiple ways to represent the same, or nearly the same number. For some numbers, there's more ways than for others, and the way that is spread across the whole range is far from "nicely shaped" in any way.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I see. Interesting. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Forgive the breadth of my question, but from understanding of basic digital circuits, an integer PRNG outputs a random number by using the XOR of certain bits of a LSFR.

That's **one** of many types of PRNGs. It's an *especially bad kind*, as it introduces linear dependency of bits. You'll rarely find that in  applications  were the *randomness* of the PRNG plays a crucial role.

It's one that is fairly possible to explain, and very small in implementation, so you'll find these very often were one just needs "some" form of noise.

When doing a PRNG for floats, you're planning to do something where numerical properties matter (otherwise, floating point numbers wouldn't be necessary).

> how does floating point PRNG work, or get implemented as far as blocks of digital circuits

You'll rarely find such a thing (they do exist), because random floating point numbers are rarely something you need in hardware. Often, using software to convert a fixed-point PRNG-generated number to floating point suffices.

**If** you need to do this in hardware, it's going to be a very special use case. So, if you find such a special use case, that will dictate how you do it.

Let's assume you're in the very special case that you need a *uniformly* distributed random variable. **I repeat:** this is an unlikely special case for a float PRNG. In almost all cases you'd use a uniform fixed-point PRNG and convert the result to float. You'd make sure that your PRNG makes adequate numbers. There's optimized PRNGs for that purpose, for example [xoroshiro256+](https://prng.di.unimi.it/).

> Or at the very least from a mathematical standpoint using bits of representation of the value to work on.

This depends heavily on what you need this for. No general statement is possible. As said, generation of floating point numbers in hardware is a rather unusual thing to do.

> Is this concept covered in a computer arithmetic course, or more broadly in a VLSI course?

Computer arithmetic courses don't concern themselves, usually, with digital hardware design.

VLSI courses will not concern themselves with super-duper-special-case problems like generating random floating point numbers.

Comment: My question of how to implement a function as such in hardware (a specific function to a hardware unit like an ASIC, or an FPGA, as opposed to a General Purpose computer, and concepts covered in the two hardware course which I now see covers topics in a different domains, that when used together can reveal more details my question.  To understand the hardware implementation details of this from a A) system level, then B) digital logic standpoint,  A) The float is generated using a cascaded stage of computation units (#1 - fixed point PRNG, followed by #2 - the floating point convert unit).

Comment: @Vahe I don't understand this comment: "how to implement this in hardware": I extensively addressed that, especially as "you don't, unless you have very specific needs for it, which you don't describe, and which would then dictate the way you do it". I can't tell you how to do an non-sensible thing sensibly!

Comment: Looks like this special case of implementation would need to be handled by a routine defined in software, rather than fixed hardware resources,  but your explanation was clarifying for my question